# What is the best generic type hint for a dataclass in python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-dataclasses

I have started using dataclasses and I have some specific one lets say for example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    job:str
    
@dataclass
class Animal:
    name: str
    age: int
```

I then have an abstract class like an interface

```
import abc
from typing import List, Dict


class NameFinder:
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_name(self, name: str,being ) :
        pass

class PersonName(NameFinder):
    def get_name(self, name:str, person:Person):
        return person.name

class AnimalName(NameFinder):
    def get_name(self, name:str, animal:Animal):
        return animal.name
```

what is a good generic type hint i can use in the abstract class as placeholder for both the Person and the Animal classes?

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with dataclasses, as far as I can tell. Seems like a red-herring. In any case,  probably, you could use a bound TypeVar `T = TypeVar(T, Animal, Person)`,

Comment: Perhaps you want a protocol class that asserts that the class received has both `name` and `age` attributes.

Comment: There's no reason for `NameFinder` to be a class, though: `get_name` can at worst be made a static method, and like most static methods can probably be implemented as a regular function instead.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i thought it might have something to do with it because the dataclass wrapper could provide a base class which I am not aware of. That is why I am asking.

Comment: @KZiovas no, it absolutely does not. That is important to understand, `dataclass.dataclasses` is a code generator, essentially, to avoid *boilerplate*. "dataclass" is not a type, which wouldn't make sense really

Comment: @chepner sure but this is a simplified example to demonstrate what I wish to achieve instead of posting the actual code. Same structure but really simple.

Comment: Note, you can always check this yourself, e.g. `print(Animal.mro())` and `print(Person.mro())`, both should only have themselves and `object`

Comment: I think this may be a case where you example is *too* simplified... but overall, `get_name` does the *exact same thing* in both subclasses, it should probably just be implemented in the base class (the abstract one in this case) annotated with a bound type variable for the `being` arugment type, or perhaps a `Protocol`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeap I did check it and they do return object. The data-class providing a base class is just an example of what could have been a solution. Another solution could exist. What I mean is that my question remains what is the best type to use for the type hints of the abstract class? Any suggestions?

Comment: This really depends on your use-case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga any examples for what I could use in cases similar to what I described?

Comment: @KZiovas again, try using `T = TypeVar("T", Animal, Person)` buuut not sure how this will play around with variance, functions are *contravariant* in their arugment types, and it always confuses me

Comment: If you were to add a third class (like `Vegetable`), you'd have to update the typevar as well. With a protocol, `Vegetable` is automatically included as a "subclass" of the protocol simply by virtue of having a `name` attribute. There are many things that other languages *must* use inheritance to implement that you can do without inheritance in Python; this is one of them.

Comment: yeah @chepner suggestions makes more sense. Protocal clas is probably what I was looking for.

Comment: @chepner yes, totally, but this depends on the exact behavior you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added a comment to my answer that might address what you are alluding to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a protocol class, which just asserts the existence of a `name` attribute.

```
from typing import Protocol


class Named(Protocol):
    name: str


class NameFinder:
    @staticmethod
    def get_name(obj: Named) -> str:
        return obj.name

# or ...
def name_finder(obj: Named) -> str:
    return obj.name
```

`get_name` and `name_finder` can both accept arguments of type `Person` or `Animal`, as both classes define a `name` attribute for their instances. There's no need to explicitly mark the classes as implementing the `Named` protocol.

Comment: yeap I thought of that but I would have preferred to avoid making another class just for that typing. Thank though.

Comment: I would consider it more like creating a different class, *replacing* `NameFinder` instead of being used *by* `NameFinder`.

Comment: ah I see, that protocl class might actually be what I want, cant I just use it diretly as the type of my `being` in my original abstract class?

Comment: Yes. Any instance (no matter what type it has) that has an attribute `name` (no matter how that attribute gets set) is considered an instance `Named`.

Comment: I'll back track a little bit: this is useful for specifying types that *have* a `name` attribute, but does nothing to *enforce* that any particular types *must* have the attribute. For that, a base class is still better, but I'm not sure how best to integrate that with a dataclass. (Most likely, it's just a case where dataclasses aren't appropriate.)

Comment: yeah i see, i am not so much worried about enforcing the attribute, this is forced in a different way in my real code, but thanks for pointing out