# How do you type-hint class prototypes that don't otherwise exist?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have legacy code with inheriting dataclasses:

```
@dataclass
class Base:
    a: int

@dataclass
class Derived1(Base):
    b: int

@dataclass
class Derived2(Base):
    b: int
```

I want to use Python type hints so that methods know when they're getting something with a `b` attribute.  However, I cannot import actual Derived1 or Derived2.  So I want something like:

```
def uses_b(b_supporting_object: TIsBaseWithB):
    ...
```

How do you define a `TIsBaseWithB`?  Is NewType related?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best generic type hint for a dataclass in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356688/what-is-the-best-generic-type-hint-for-a-dataclass-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol):

```py
from typing import Protocol


class SupportsB(Protocol):
    b: int
```

Comment: Is there any way to say "this protocol includes all of what dataclass Base brings, plus these other few things"?

Comment: What you're asking for is an intersection type of both `SupportsB` and `Base`. Something like `Intersection[SupportsB, Base]`. This is not supported by Python's type system at the moment. Alternatively, you can extend the `SupportsB` protocol with all attributes from the `Base` class,

Comment: Can you make Base class inherit from SupportsB?

Comment: `Base` itself does not support `b`, though.